# Continuity over a Compact Implies Uniform Continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

There is a well-known theorem in mathematical analysis that says

> Suppose $f:M\to N$ is a function from a metric space $(M,d_M)$ to another metric space $(N,d_N)$. Assume that $M$ is compact. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous over $(M,d_M)$.

For now, let us take $M=[a,b]$, $N=\mathbb{R}$, $d_M=d_N=|\cdot|$. I have seen two different proofs for this case.

- T. A. Apostol, Calculus, Volume 1, 2nd Edition, Page 152, 1967.
- C. C. Pugh, Real Mathematical Analysis, 2nd Edition, Page 85, 2015.

Apostol argues by contradiction using the method of bisections and the least upper bound property. Pugh also explains by contradiction but prefers to use a technique that one of my teachers called it continuous induction to prove that $[a\,\,\,b]$ is sequentially compact and then uses this property to prove the theorem. Both proofs can be found on the pages mentioned above.

Recently, I noticed that Pugh has suggested another approach in exercise 43 of chapter 1 on page 52. However, I couldn't riddle it out. Here is the question

> 43. Prove that a continuous function defined on an interval $[a\,\,\,b]$ is uniformaly continuous.
>
> **Hint**. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Think of $\epsilon$ as fixed and consider the sets
> \begin{align*}A(\delta)&=\{u\in[a,b]\,|\,\text{if}\,x,t\in[a,u]\,\text{and}\,|x-t|<\delta\,\text{then}\,|f(x)-f(t)|<\epsilon\}, \\
> A&=\bigcup_{\delta>0}A(\delta).
> \end{align*}
> Using the least upper bound property, prove that $b\in A$. Infer that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Can you shed some light on what Pugh is trying to suggest in the hint?

---

**Uniform Continuity**

In the definition of continuity we have that

$$\forall x\in[a,b],\,\,\forall\epsilon>0,\,\,\exists\delta>0,\,\,\forall t\in[a,b]\,\wedge\,|t-x|<\delta\,\implies|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Here the delta depends on $x$ and $\epsilon$. Now, fix $\epsilon$ and let $\Delta_{\epsilon}$ be the set that contains all values of $\delta$ corresponding to different $x$'s. Then uniform continuity is just telling us that $\Delta_\epsilon$ has a minimum. Consequently, this means that there is a $\delta$ that works for all $x\in[a,b]$. This leads to the following definition

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\,\,\exists\delta>0,\,\,\forall x\in[a,b],\,\,\forall t\in[a,b]\,\wedge\,|t-x|<\delta\,\implies|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

where $\delta$ only depends on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is indeed the largest domain over which $f$ is uniformly continuous. Let it be defined as below (not the one in the question)

$$A := \big\{u \in [a, b] \, | \, \text{f is uniformly continuous over} \, [a, u] \big\}$$

We proceed as follows. There seems to be four steps in a continuous induction.

**0. Existence of Supremum.** We know that $a\in A$ and that $A$ is bounded above by $b$. This means that $A$ has a supremum $c:=\sup A$ with $a\leq c\leq b$.

**1. Initialization.** If $c=a$ then by the continuity at $a$ we observe that there is a $\delta_1>0$ such that for every $u\in[a,a+\delta_1)$ we have $|f(u)-f(a)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now, for every $x, t\in[a,a+\delta_1)$ we have that $|f(x)-f(t)|\leq|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)-f(t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$ This means that $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[a,c_*]$ for any $c_*\in(a,a+\delta_1)$. Consequently, $c_*\in A$ which contradicts the fact that $c=a$ was an upper bound for $A$.

**2. Induction Step.** If $a<c<b$ then for *every* $\delta>0$ there is a $v\in A$ such that $v\in(c-\delta,c)$ otherwise $c-\delta$ would be an upper bound for $A$ contradicting that $c$ is the least upper bound for $A$. Again, by continuity at $c$ we can conclude that there is a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for every $x,t\in(c-\delta_2,c+\delta_2)$ we have $|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Choose $v \in (c - \delta_2, c)$ such that $v \in A$ and choose $c_* \in (c, c + \delta_2)$. We see that $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[a,v]$ and $[v,c_*]$ so it is uniformly continuous over $[a,c_*]$ and $c_*\in A$ (This part needs more detail so try to fill it out). But $c_*>c$ which contradicts $c$ being an upper bound for $A$.

**3. Termination.** This leaves us with the only option that $c=b$. Using the continuity at $b$ we know that for every $x,t\in(b-\delta,b]$ we have $|f(x)-f(t)|<\epsilon$. Also, there is a $c_*\in A$ such that $c_*\in(b-\delta, b]$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[a,c_*]$ and $[c_*,b]$ then it is uniformly continuous over $[a,b]$. Equivalently, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $b\in A(\delta)$ that implies $b\in A$.

Comment: Since we have fixed epsilon at the start, saying f is uniformly continuous over so and so interval is not technically correct. And this is actually significant since you say "f is uniformly continuous over [a,v] and over [v,c*], so it is over [a,c*]". But this doesn't work since this doesn't imply c* is in A, since it doesn't necessarily satisfy the condition for the same epsilon that we started with.

Comment: Since $\epsilon$ is a fixed number, it doesn't actually follow that $f$ having that property on $[a,v]$ and on $[v,c_*]$ implies f has that property on $[a,c_*]$.

Comment: To complete the argument, you have to give another clever argument, using continuity of $f$ at a couple points, and the observation that if we insist $x$ and $t$ are $\frac{\delta}{2}$ close then either they are both in a $\delta$ neighborhood of $c$ or they are both in $[a,v]$

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: You are welcomed to write a new answer then. :) However, my intuition about uniform continuity tells me that the argument is fine!

Comment: I might write an answer. But nonetheless, saying "my intuition tells me it's fine" when presented with a logical gap in an argument is a terrible practice to have, especially if your goal is to learn mathematics rather than something else

Comment: Your "intuition" doesn't matter, there is a precise definition, which is not satisfied just by what you have used, so it can not be "fine"

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: 
I thought about your point, Now, I understand what you mean. It is an an old answer and at the time of writing it I was thinking that we have defined 
as {∈[,]|f is uniformly continuous over[,]} but I did not point this out explicitly. With this in mind the argument works fine. However, I would like to see your answer based on the other definition of $A$ mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a\in A$, since $x,t\in[a,a]$ implies $|f(x)-f(t)|=0<\epsilon$.

Assume $c\in A$. Then, from continuity at $c$ there is $\delta$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon/2$. Then, if $x,t$ are $\delta$-close to $c$, then $|f(x)-f(t)|\leq|f(x)-f(c)|+|f(t)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. Therefore, $[c,\delta/2]\subset A$.

Let $b'$ be the supremum of the $c$ such that $[a,c]\subset A$. The argument above shows that if $b'<b$, then there is $\delta>0$ such that $[b',b+\delta]\subset A$ contradicting that $b'$ is the supremum.

Therefore, $b'=b$.

---

The argument has an inductive structure in that you check it for the initial point $a$. Then, assuming the conclusion for a set $[a,b']$ you prove that it is satisfied for $[a,b'+\delta]$ for some $\delta>0$. The combination of them gives that it holds on $[a,b]$ all $b$.

Comment: $b\in A$ implies $b\in A(\delta)$ for some $\delta$. That is the final $\delta$

Comment: @H.R. $c$ is a number. $b'$ is the supremum of the set $\{c\in[a,b]: [a,c]\subset A\}$. The final $\delta$ is one for which $b\in A(\delta)$. The sets $A(\delta)$ are just the points for which the property in the uniform continuity is satisfied for $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. I managed to write it in a slightly different way. I would be happy if you take a look at my ansewr.

Comment: You can't assume x,t are delta close to c, to show [c,c+delta/2] is contained in A. You have to show it holds if x,t are delta close to each other