# Continuity on closed interval implies uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem: Prove that a continuous function $f$ defined on an interval [a,b] is uniformly continuous using only the least upper bound property of real numbers.

The following hint is given: Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Define $$ A(\delta) = \{ u \in [a,b] : \textrm{ if } x,t \in [a,u] \textrm{ and } |x-t|<\delta \textrm{ then } |f(x)-f(t)|<\epsilon\}$$ and $$ A = \cup_{\delta>0} A(\delta).$$ Using the least upper bound property, prove that $$b \in A.$$

I am proceeding as follows. Let $c = sup A$. We know $b$ is an upper bound of $A$. Hence $c \leq b$. I then try to show that $c<b$ leads to a contradiction as follows: suppose $c<b$. Then there is a $t$ between $c$ and $b$. Since $c$ is the least upper bound of $A$, and $c<t<b$, we have $t \notin A$.

Now consider the interval $[a,t]$. Since $t \notin A$, there exists $v,w \in [a,t]$ such that for no $\delta>0$ do we have $|v-w|<\delta \implies |f(v)-f(w)|<\epsilon$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Since $v \in [a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $v$; hence there exists a $\delta(v,\epsilon)>0$ such that $z \in [a,b]$ and $|z-v|<\delta(v,\epsilon)$ implies that $|f(z)-f(v)|<\epsilon$.

Finally, to prove that $b \in A$, I use the same argument: if $b \notin A$, then there exists $v,w \in [a,b]$ such that for no $\delta>0$ do we have $|v-w|<\delta \implies |f(v)-f(w)|<\epsilon$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

I am not completely sure that the proof is correct. Any comments or suggestions will be most welcome.

Comment: In the paragraph that starts "Now consider the interval $[a,t]$", the next sentence is wrong. You can say "For each $\delta >0$ there exist  $v_{\delta}$ and $w_{\delta}$  such that ..." but this seems to take us in a circle.

Comment: Yes. Let me rewrite that. $\forall \delta>0, \exists v_{\delta}, w_{\delta} \in [a,t]$ such that $|v_{\delta}-w_{\delta}|<\delta$ and $|f(v_{\delta})-f(w_{\delta})|\geq\epsilon$.

Comment: But then you don't get the desired contradiction.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found a discussion of the same question some years ago and an approach to the solution (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540234/continuity-over-a-compact-implies-uniform-continuity)